# Change the output of find command

Tags: linux, bash, variables, find

Hello guys I'm using the find command to find the .apk files in a directory. But the output of the find command is **./**foo.apk.

I don't want to have this **./**.

```
cd output/dist
output_apk=`find ./ -name "*.apk" -print0`
echo "$output_apk"
```

The output is ./foo.apk.
I have try the sed command with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find output/dist -name "*.apk" |
sed 's%^output/dist/%%'
```

This also avoids the useless `cd` and removes the erroneous `-print0`. If you are not piping into a program which requires null-terminated input, this option is wrong.

Comment: Can I use this with the variable output_apk= ?

Comment: Of course you can assign the result to a variable if you like, although capturing just so you can `echo` it is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)